# Need help to implement audio recording in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, red5

I want to integrate audio recording functionality in rails 3 application, where user can able record their voice and to share it,  I don't know the way to proceed this.

I googled and found that red5 with flash player is the solution for this,but I didn't find any tutorials to integrate red5 and flash, can anybody suggest me any tutorials or some other ways  to implement this since I am pretty noob at this.

Answer (score 0):

There are sample applications in every red5 distribution. 
You might simply install a Red5 version on your local machine and run the web-installer to get the demo applications.
Try out the "olfaDemo", this is a recording application.

You will be required to code a minimum in ActionScript3.
The sample applications are all done with plain ActionScript3 and/or Flex.
So you either need Adobe Flash CS or Flex Builder.
You might also try with OpenLaszlo.